# Compiling scss files using gulp-sass npm module

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-sass

I am using [`gulp-sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass) module to compile scss files to css files.

This is my `gulpfile.js`

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

I have two files in my sass folder:

```
sass
|--- _test.scss
|--- demo.scss
```

The plugin compiles demo.scss file but not *_test.scss*, I tried with same content as well.

Is there something with the naming convention or I need to change my gulpfile.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `_test.scss` to `test.scss`.

Node sass ignores `_filenames`. Usually we use `_` with files names which are going to be imported in the `scss` files.

Comment: so we can only use this `_*.scss` for imports

Comment: Yes for `@import "test.scss"` or  `@import "test"`. You can import test inside the `demo.scss`